# What goes into the '.vim' folder, can I store my own stuff there?

Tags: vimrc

I want to put some customizations of mine in the .vim folder, actually a subdirectory because I don't want to many .files in my home directory.

Is that alright or is the .vim directory restricted to some kind of `approved` plugins and other users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.vim` directory under your home directory is used by Vim as the first place to search for vim scripts after starting up.

It's fine to add your own files, in fact a lot of plugins or plugin managers already do under their own subdirectory. Just be careful not to name your files or subdirectories anything that is already used by Vim. Take a look at the ['runtimepath'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27runtimepath%27) documentation for a list.

Starting from version 7.4 you can even put your `.vimrc` file in the `.vim` directory to declutter your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

you can put your files there at will.

you can also create your own directories there.